# error parsing json in C# ASP.NET Core .NET

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net

I am trying to parse json into dynamic object (ASP.Net Core with .NET RC2) and running into the below error.

What am i doing wrong here?

```cs
string jsn = @"
{
    'success': false,
    'error': 
    {
        'code': 101,
        'type': 'missing_access_key',
        'info': 'You have not supplied an API Access Key. [Required format: access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY]'
    }
}";

dynamic jObject2 = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsn);

var s2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsn);
```

Output from execution in immediate window

> jObject2.success
> error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'success' and no accessible extension method 'success' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> s2.success
> error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'success' and no accessible extension method 'success' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Your code runs successfully, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/EkTJT1.  Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].  Your current question doesn't even show an attempt to access the `"success"` property.

Comment: jObject2.success, its there; i did execution in immediate window

Comment: What happens if you try to do it in your code rather than in the immediate window?  Does the problem only happen in the immediate window, or does it happen everywhere?

Comment: its the same problem/error in the code as well